# how to delete space from tuple in python code?

Tags: python, sql

I have a python code that connects to an oracle database and by using `select` returns me data and saves data in the file. **I need to remove spaces in this saved data!** Here is my code

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'login/password@ip/user'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u"SELECT * FROM subs_histories WHERE subs_subs_id IN (SELECT subs_subs_id FROM subs_histories where end_date < start_date GROUP BY subs_subs_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)  ORDER BY subs_subs_id, start_date, end_date")

with open('subs_histories.cvs', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for row in c:
        print(row[0],";", row[1],";", row[2],";", row[3],";", row[4],";", row[5], file=f)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Some one has downvoted you but hasn't given any feedback so I will. You will be more likely to get answers if you share an example of the data you wish to remove the spaces from, and your desired output.

Comment: @scotty3785 now output in file is like this ```10065 ; 13 ; 1195 ; 2019-01-30 17:32:59 ; 2019-01-31 11:52:57 ; CC:OAPI:boris``` **I want to remove spaces before each semicolon**

Comment: Use the `csv` module (it's built into Python) to create CSV files. There are *tons* of examples on the Internet and there's documentation, it's easy to learn.

Comment: @Tomalak thnx lot. I`ve found documentation. Really easier to solve the problem. But If anyone has another way of solution, I`ll be pleasat

Comment: What "other way"? You want to create a CSV file - use the `csv` module. It's simple. There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Use `sep=''` argument in `print()`.

Comment: @Tomalak yes I`m using **csv** module right now, but still want to know whether there are other ways of solution of this problem ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to run rstrip and lstrip on each of the tuple elements before you write it to the text file

Convert your example text back in to a tuple (in your case you would just use `row`)

```
d1 = "10065 ; 13 ; 1195 ; 2019-01-30 17:32:59 ; 2019-01-31 11:52:57 ; CC:OAPI:boris"
d2 = tuple(d1.split(';'))
```

Which give us a tuple still containing spaces

```
('10065 ', ' 13 ', ' 1195 ', ' 2019-01-30 17:32:59 ', ' 2019-01-31 11:52:57 ', ' CC:OAPI:boris')
```

To remove the spaces, do the following.

```
no_spaces = tuple(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().lstrip(), d2))
```

This means, for every element inside d2, run the anonymous/lambda function to remove the spaces to the left and to right of the text and put each value back in to a tuple.

Results in

```
('10065', '13', '1195', '2019-01-30 17:32:59', '2019-01-31 11:52:57', 'CC:OAPI:boris')
```

As has been said in the comments, you can use the csv writer to output the data as a csv file (but specifying the seperator as a semi-colon) but that wasn't your question.

Modifying your original example (I don't have oracle to run so this is a guess)

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'login/password@ip/user'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u"SELECT * FROM subs_histories WHERE subs_subs_id IN (SELECT subs_subs_id FROM subs_histories where end_date < start_date GROUP BY subs_subs_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)  ORDER BY subs_subs_id, start_date, end_date")

with open('subs_histories.cvs', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for row in c:
        row = tuple(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().lstrip(), row))
        print(row[0],";", row[1],";", row[2],";", row[3],";", row[4],";", row[5], file=f)
conn.close()
```

You have reported a problem that some of your values aren't strings so you can't use `lstrip` or `rstrip`. You can change the lambda function to only try to strip the spaces if it is a string, otherwise just output the value. See below for a possible solution.

```
row = tuple(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().lstrip() if isinstance(x,str) else x, row))
```

Alternatively (and more hacky)

```
row = tuple(map(lambda x: str(x).rstrip().lstrip(), row))
```

Comment: what does ```c2``` stand for? IDE gives message that ```c2``` is not defined in this code

Comment: @МухаммадёрЖураев A typo. Change to `c`.

Comment: still not works **row = tuple(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().lstrip(), row))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rstrip'**

Comment: Your original data example didn't include any integers. I'll make an edit to my post to try to resolve the issue. This demonstrates the importance of sharing accurate information in your question.